# JAX-RS boolean vs int

Tags: java, web-services, annotations, boolean, jax-rs

I have a method which takes a boolean value

```
@GET
@Path("/updatePassword/{userid}/{password}/{resetTemporary}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean updatePassword(@PathParam("userid") String userid, @PathParam("password") String password, @PathParam("resetTemporary") boolean resetTemporary) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (!StringUtilities.stringEmptyOrNull(userid, password)) {
        result = factory.updatePasssword(userid, password, resetTemporary);
        logger.info("Updated user password for user " + userid+ " Action completed = " + result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It appears after some testing / playing around that in my url i can in fact pass an int instead of a boolean. The interesting thing is, no matter whether I passed a 1 or a 0, it still came back as false.

Is this because the value was not recognised and therefore defaults to false, if so, how do you enforce the caller to use a true/false expression?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "it still came back as false" did you mean that updatePassword came back as false or that your parameter, resetTemporary, was always false?

Comment: the parameter was always false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little testing it appears passing `1` into `resetTemporary` (or similar `boolean` field) will always result in `false`, whether you use `@PathParam` or `@QueryParam`.

To enforce the caller to use a "true/false" expression you may need to change the parameter to a `String` and put in validation code that expects `"true"` or `"false"` and throws an error is something else comes through.

**Update**: Thought of some other possibilities.

- I mention a `String` above but it need not be a String. Any type from which you could gather the required information would do.
- You could also split the REST method into two methods (e.g. `updatePassword` and `resetPassword`, going by your variable names). The two methods may be very similar and call the same helper methods but then each one would know the value of the `resetTemporary` parameter and would be able to act accordingly.

Personally, I would favor the second approach. Boolean parameters are generally a sign that a method is doing two separate (though perhaps very similar) things. Splitting them into two would ensure each method is doing one thing and remove one parameter, `resetTemporary`, from each, reducing complexity.